# A few doubts about creating my own webhosting server

Tags: linux, networking, apache-http-server, postgresql

I just created a system administration website from scratch for one of my university's administration offices (for free) using a postgresql database. I have tested this new system for almost 3 weeks and everything works great, however, my university does not allow me to host it in one of their servers and the people from this administration office are delighted with the new system but they are not much likely to help with anything related with webhosting funding.

After the unsupportive response from my university, I decided to create my own webserver and run this new system from my house using an old computer running Scientific Linux 6.2, however, I have a few doubts about the initial setup:

1. If I want my own webhosting server, is it mandatory to have a static IP or can I use the dynamic IP from my DHCP router home?
2. Do I need to buy a domain or is there any possibility to create my own domain for this system?
3. Once I have conditions 1 and 2 fulfilled, which open source software would be more convenient to use: the traditional Apache web server or the Russian Nginx web server?

Finally, I would like to know if I am missing something else or what's the next step that I should take about the installation setup of my webserver.

Comment: Considered using an AWS EC2 micro instance on the free usage tier? Might be easier and more convenient.

Comment: Word of caution - you're missing step 1: gain management support. Right now you're circumventing that and doing it with your own resources. I applaud the initiative but this could end up creating some liabilities for you. Your best bet is to have administration get noisy about it to their bosses and set up some meetings to convince management of how awesome of a tool this is. However, i wouldn't expect any compensation for it. More likely is that you'd  give them the system, the manuals, and the keys so their IT staff could take it over.

Answer (score 0):

> is it mandatory to have a static IP or can I use the dynamic IP from
>   my DHCP router home?

It's typically regarded as mandatory. But you can use some dynamic DNS facility to always keep the right IP address in the DNS. It's possible to run a web service on a dynamic IP that way.

> Do I need to buy a domain or is there any possibility to create my own domain for this system?

You can use a fake domain for your own purposes but for the public facing names you need access to at least one registered global DNS domain.

> Once I have conditions 1 and 2 fulfilled, which open source software would be more
>   convenient to use: the traditional Apache web server or the Russian Nginx web server?

It depends purely on your needs. The main differences will be on the application level so first have to define which programming languages and frameworks you want to support and then you should check the web servers and their features.